# How to check which argument is running in a thread

Tags: python

I have a list of threads each of which takes a function run([sql_query_1, sql_query_2...]). The argument to the function is a list of SQL queries. Some of these queries are invalid and raise an exception in the run() function.

Is there a way to check inside the thread, which query is running in the run() function so I can suppress that exception? (I cannot modify run())

```
threads = []
for _ in range(x):
    t = Thread(target = run(), args=[list_of_queries])
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    if # check if invalid query is running in t.start(), then suppress 
       # the error that run() will raise for that query
    else: # continue running normally
```